# Jenkins Plugin for Artifact Analysis

Tags: java, plugins, jenkins

I need to create a Jenkins post build plugin that will open the artifact (an tar.gz file) and retrieve some information from it. The problem is I'm not sure what is the best entry point to use for this case and how to get the artifact path to open it.

Have you already had a similar problem like that?

Comment: Is it necessary to use a plugin? Wouldn't a bash-script that runs after the build be enough?

Comment: It's not necessary, but it's preferable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Follow the tutorial to create a basic Hello World plug-in and understand the code and how it works.
2. Modify the class to extend Recorder instead of Builder, modify the **public static final class DescriptorImpl** to extend Publisher :

   public static final class DescriptorImpl extends
               BuildStepDescriptor{
   }

Also create a class that will implement Action, this class will have some get-ers for plugin name, url, icon and so on. You can return empty string for them for now.

3. modify the jelly files.

You can get the path using a textbox in jelly script. For example you can use the textbox to set a location where the artifact will be stored and in plug-in implement a method that will search for it.

Also, if you need help creating a Jenkins post-build plugin, I suggest you to take a look at the jacoco and eclemma plugins, especially at the classes that contains Action, Recorder, Builder in their names.

Comment: @FelipeWannmacher You're welcom!